# PrimeNg Table dynamic cell edit control

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I've following [PrimeNG Table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table)

[image]

Here is the [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ii4oz6).

All three columns are editable. "Property Name" column always renders Text box in edit whereas "Property Value Type" column always renders a dropdown.

But for **Property Value column** I want to either render Text box or Dropdown depending on following two conditions:

1. **Text box** if "Property Value Type" cell value for that row is **String**
2. **Dropdown** if "Property Value Type" cell value for that row is **Boolean**

I've added conditional edit controls in the grid HTML. When I change the value for "Property Value Type" cell from String to Boolean (or other way around), then "Property Value" cell for that row should render Dropdown but it still shows a Text box (unless I trigger pagination event or sort event).

How do I refresh the specific cell?

**Component:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  tableColumns = [
    { field: 'propName', header: 'Property Name' },
    { field: 'propValue', header: 'Property Value' },
    { field: 'propValueType', header: 'Property Value Type' },
  ];
  booleanOptions = [{ label: 'true', value: 'true' }, { label: 'false', value: 'false' }];
  propValueTypeOptions = [{ label: 'String', value: 'String' }, { label: 'Boolean', value: 'Boolean' }];
  tableItems = [
    { propName: 'prop 1', propValue: 'value 1', propValueType: 'String' },
    { propName: 'prop 2', propValue: 'true', propValueType: 'Boolean' },
    { propName: 'prop 3', propValue: 'value 3', propValueType: 'String' },
    { propName: 'prop 4', propValue: 'true', propValueType: 'Boolean' },
    { propName: 'prop 5', propValue: 'value 5', propValueType: 'String' },
    { propName: 'prop 6', propValue: 'true', propValueType: 'Boolean' },
    { propName: 'prop 7', propValue: 'value 7', propValueType: 'String' },
    { propName: 'prop 8', propValue: 'true', propValueType: 'Boolean' },
    { propName: 'prop 9', propValue: 'value 9', propValueType: 'String' },
    { propName: 'prop 10', propValue: 'true', propValueType: 'Boolean' },
  ];


  refreshGrid() {
    const temp = [...this.tableItems];
    this.tableItems = temp;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.tableItems = [...temp];
    }, 0);
  }

  showPropNameEditCellTextBox(col) {
    return (col.field === 'propName');
  }

  showPropValueTypeEditDdl(col) {
    return (col.field === 'propValueType');
  }

  showPropValueTxtIfString(rowData, col) {
    return (col.field === 'propValue' && rowData.propValueType === 'String');
  }

  showPropValueDdlIfBoolean(rowData, col) {
    return (col.field === 'propValue' && rowData.propValueType === 'Boolean');
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p-table [columns]="tableColumns" [value]="tableItems" [paginator]="true" [rows]="15" resizableColumns="true" responsive="true"
     [rowHover]="true" derableColumns="true">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                    {{col.header}}
                    <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
            <tr>
                <td pEditableColumn *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    <p-cellEditor>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                            {{rowData[col.field]}}
                        </ng-template>

            <!-- Show text box for "Property Name" column -->
                        <ng-template pTemplate="input" *ngIf="showPropNameEditCellTextBox(col)">
                            <input pInputText [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control" />
            </ng-template>
            <!-- Show text box for "Property Name" column /-->

            <!-- Show Text for "Property Value" column if Property Value Type column is "String" -->
            <ng-template pTemplate="input" *ngIf="showPropValueTxtIfString(rowData, col)">
              <input pInputText [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control" />
            </ng-template>
            <!-- Show Text for "Property Value" column if Property Value Type column is "String" /-->

            <!-- Show Dropdown for "Property Value" column if Property Value Type column is "Boolean" -->
            <ng-template pTemplate="input" *ngIf="showPropValueDdlIfBoolean(rowData, col)">
              <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]">
                <option *ngFor="let item of booleanOptions" class="form-control" [value]="item.value">{{item.label}}</option>
              </select>            
            </ng-template>
            <!-- Show Dropdown for "Property Value" column if Property Value Type column is "Boolean" /-->

            <!-- Show dropdown for "Property Value Type" column -->
            <ng-template pTemplate="input" *ngIf="showPropValueTypeEditDdl(col)">
              <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" (change)="refreshGrid()">
                <option *ngFor="let item of propValueTypeOptions" class="form-control" [value]="item.value">{{item.label}}</option>
              </select>
            </ng-template>
            <!-- Show dropdown for "Property Value Type" column /-->
                    </p-cellEditor>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

PrimeNG Table detects changes based on the reference of the value changes, so just creating a new object or making deep copy should solve your issue

To make a deep copy use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))` or use [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) from  lodash

```
refreshGrid() {
    let temp = [...this.tableItems];
    temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp));
    this.tableItems = temp;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.tableItems = [...temp];
    }, 0);
}
```

Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdkeda)

Comment: Working like a charm